# Give an assignment until it reaches a number, after that another assignment, and so on

Tags: java

I want to make an algorithm that will print out for exemple, "that is ok" until the number 0.25. And after that it says "warning", so when it reaches 0.3 it warns one person (one variable, let's call it person A); When the value raises up to 0.4 it warns two people (person A and person B); And finally, when it reaches 0.5 it warns three people (person A, person B, person C).

So, I don't know which variables to use, but going one step at a time, I came up with the following;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner mc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double ind;
        ind = mc.nextDouble();

        switch (ind){
        case 0.25:
            System.out.println("Ok");
            break;
        case 0.3:
            System.out.println("Warning");
            break;
        case 0.4:
            System.out.println("danger");
        }
    }

}
```

now, i know switch is only usable to int variables. But I guess my logic was at the frakking least, in the right place XD.
Help anyone?

---

So here, is What I came up with, but now I got a new problem, I want that the value start from 0 and move up to 0.25 without anyone typing, i guess just like "for". I donno, maybe i'm too noob to make sense.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner mc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Level of radiation: ");
    double ind = mc.nextDouble();
    if (ind <= 0.25) {
           System.out.println("Ok");
        } else if (ind <= 0.3) {
           System.out.println("Warning");
        } else if (ind <= 0.4) {
           System.out.println("danger");
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I voted this down because it's actually two questions, neither of which is very clear.

Comment: Given all the replies JayNpc has been making to people's answers, he doesn't know enough about programming in Java to complete this project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will be less confused when you split the things to two variables: The text and the recipients:

```
private void sendAllMessages(double ind) {
  String text;
  if (ind < 0.25) {
    text = "Ok";
  } else if (ind < 0.30) {
    text = "Warning";
  } else {
    text = "Danger";
  }

  // A always gets a message
  sendMessage(text, A);

  // B was annoyed of the many messages
  if (ind >= 0.40) {
    sendMessage(text, B);
  }

  // C is really important and has lots of other emails, so keep him quiet
  if (ind >= 0.50) {
    sendMessage(text, C);
  }
}
```

To test this code, you should write a very simple `sendMessage` method, and then run the following:

```
@Test
public void testSendMessages() {
  for (int level = 0; level < 100; level++) {
    double ind = level / 100.0; /* note the ".0" at the end; that's important. */
    sendAllMessages(ind);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, the structure helped me understand a lot more. But one question, how do I assigned those A, B and C to the variables there? It says B  cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Why the .0 at the end is important? also, the level++ means that it will keep adding until it reaches 100 right? So that means with that code it won't be necessary to the user input the value?

Comment: I don't know what your `A`, `B` and `C` are. Maybe they are email addresses, maybe postal addresses. That's also the reason why I didn't implement the `sendMessage` method. If it's just for testing, you can just write `String A = "A", B = "B", C = "C";`.

Comment: No, the `level++` only means *add one to `level`*. But together with the whole `for` loop, this means *start with `level` being `0`, and while it is still `< 100`, run the following code and then do the `level++`*.

Comment: The difference between `99 / 100` and `99 / 100.0` is a lot. The first expression evaluates to `0`, because division with integer numbers returns only whole numbers. The second expression evaluates to a floating point number that is very close to `0.99`, but it's not exactly this value. This is just a hint, so as you see, there is still much to learn.

Comment: Thank you Roland, indeed I need to learn more. But with your help and Roflcoptr I'll get there faster (:

Answer (score 0):

You should not use switch in this case since you're not testing a "sharp" value but a range:

```
if (ind <= 0.25) {
   System.out.println("Ok");
} else if (ind <= 0.3) {
   System.out.println("Warning");
} else if (ind <= 0.4) {
   System.out.println("danger");
}
```

From the comments I assume that you need something like this:

```
public class Person {

   private double ind;
   private String name;

   public Person(double ind, String name) {
      this.ind = ind;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void printWarning() {
      if (ind <= 0.25) {
         System.out.println("Ok");
      } else if (ind <= 0.3) {
         System.out.println("Warning");
      } else if (ind <= 0.4) {
        System.out.println("danger");
      }
   }

}
```

Then you can invoke it like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Person a = new Person(0.25, a);
   Person b = new Person(0.3, b);
   Person c = new Person(0.4, c);

   ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
   persons.add(a);
   persons.add(b);
   persons.add(c);

   foreach (Person p: persons) {
      p.printWarning();
   }
}
```

Comment: And if I want to set those printouts to a specific group? For example, when it reaches 0.3 the "warning" shall be delivered to "group A". How should it be the command?

Comment: @JayNpc It totally depends how you implement these groups.

Comment: @JayNpc You have to somehow represent these groups in the code. Is Group a class? Or just a variable?

Comment: It's somehow like @Asaf said. I should have say that I want to link the results of the variable with "person A", if I make any sense at all. Lemme rephrase: if (ind <= 0.25) than person A reads OK, else (ind <= 0.4) than person A and B reads danger.

Comment: @JayNpc Then I would create a group class that consist of a name and the variable ind.

Comment: @Roflcoptr look, i have edited with my latest try out. Now I want that the number vary from 0 to 0.25 without typing it. how do i do that?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Using `double`s as loop counters is dangerous, since `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

Comment: @Roland Illig yes that is true. You could also predefine a array of doubles to iterate over.

Comment: I think you got me confused with the new variables there soldier. I'm not familiar with ArrayList

Comment: @JayNpc Ok I'm really sorry but then I don't know how I can help you. I'm not really sure what you're asking but I think you should read a little bit about Java fundamentals like objects, classes, lists, loops etc.

Comment: I'll check the ArrayList, but I guess what you and @Roland said is true. It helped me, but i'm still a bit confused

Comment: @Roland Say, if I use for (float ind = 0; ind < 0.50; ind+=0.1) that, the if (ind <=0.25) will work?

Comment: @JayNpc: Yes, it will work in this case. But in general it is dangerous. Try this code: `for (double x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.01) { System.out.println(x); }`, and before you run that code, try to predict what it does. Then compare it with the actual result. Be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
Map<Float, Person> notificationMap = new TreeMap<Float,Person>();
notificationMap.put(0.1, A);
notificationMap.put(0.3, B);
notificationMap.put(0.4, C);

...

ind = mc.nextDouble();
Collection<Person> persons = notificationMap.headMap(ind).values();

for (Person p : persons) {
  notify(p);
}
```

I probably wouldn't implement this way for efficiency reasons, but I think it is very readable.

TreeMap [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for more info.

Comment: wow, so many variables i haven't seen yet. i need to get my mind around it. care to explain?

Comment: well the treemap is just a sorted map. in this case sorted on the float keys. the `headMap(float)` returns a sub-map containing all the entries in the original map whose float key is less than the given value (the value of ind) and `values()` just returns the values of the sub map which in this case are Person objects. So for a value of 0.32 you would get back a collection = { A, B }