# Cannot convert double to boolean (noob here)

Tags: java, syntax

This is my algorithm, and my goal here is to set an "if statement". Take a look:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("This is occurring right now");

        for (float ind = 0; ind <= 0.50; ind += 0.1) {
            System.out.println(ind);
        }

        double find;
        if (find = 0.25);
```

At last line, it says "I cannot convert double to boolean".
How should I proceed? (I'm a begginer with little time to finish this assignment, like today)

---

Okay, I looked all of your tips and came up with that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("this is occouring right now");

        for (float ind = 0; ind <= 0.50; ind += 0.1) {
            System.out.println(ind);
        }

        double find = 0;
        if (find == 0.25) {
            System.out.println("Group A has been Warned");
        } else if (find == 0.30) {
            System.out.println("Group A and B need to shut down");
        } else if (find == 0.40) {
            System.out.println("All Groups (A, B and C) need to shut down");
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that by setting the `if` statement there, it would show me the warnings when it runs.

How do I call again what's being typed inside `System.out.println()`?
I'm always calling print-outs... What now?

---

tweaked

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple {
public static void main(String args []) {
    Scanner dic = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("type the rate: ");
    for (double ind=dic.nextDouble(); ind <=0.50; ind+=0.1){

        // include my variables

        if (ind == 0.2){
        System.out.println("Group A has been Warned");

    }else if (ind == 0.3){
        System.out.println("Group A and B need to shut down");
    }else if (ind == 0.4){
        System.out.println("All Groups (A, B and C) need to shut down");
    }
}
}
}
```

i guess im going into the right direction with that one. donno. the thing is, I typed 0.2 and it showed two warnings. It should show only one. I suppose.

Comment: You should have started sooner :) `if (find == 0.25)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If` statement wants a boolean inside the parentheses

you can check [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple {

public static void main(String args []) {    

System.out.println("this is occurring right now");    

for (float ind=0; ind <=0.50; ind+=0.1){        
System.out.println(ind);    
}    

double find;    

if (find == 0.25);// when it's "=" it sets find as 0.25, when it is "==" it compares the two values
```

version two: If you want only one if to work you should use a `break` at the end of the `if` statements what this will do is that after processing the if statements which meets your ind condition it will get out of the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class apple {
   public static void main(String args []) {

     Scanner dic = new Scanner(System.in);    
     System.out.println("type the rate: "); 

     for (double ind=dic.nextDouble(); ind <=0.50; ind+=0.1){        
     // include my variables        
        if (ind == 0.2){        
          System.out.println("Group A has been Warned");  
          break;  
        }
        else if (ind == 0.3){        
          System.out.println("Group A and B need to shut down");  
          break;  
        }
         else if (ind == 0.4){        
           System.out.println("All Groups (A, B and C) need to shut down"); 
           break;   
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello again. Now it says "it cannot be resolved to a variable" (i'm using the same lines as you see here.) But i thought my variable were stated in the for -> float process. isn't ?

Comment: @JayNpc I have been there so many times, good luck on your programming journey ^^

Comment: @JayNpc update your question so everyone can have another look Jay.And point which line the error occurs.

Comment: Also initialize your variable find like this: double find=0;

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz ok Emre I've edited. I guess i'm heading to the right direction (loL) but i can't figure it out why is not doing what I want (with the code up i just edit up here).

Comment: @JayNpc so what is the problem now?your code doesn't seem to have any error to me.

Comment: @JayNpc buddy if you want to see this System.out.println("Group A has been Warned"); on the screen do this double find = 0.25; or else you cant get nothing written on the screen because find is zero.

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz When I run, I want to show to the user that when it reaches 0.25 it will show a warning. And the same thing when it reaches, 0.30, 0.40. But that doesn't happen. It only shows the for loop until it reaches 0.5 and that's that.

Comment: @JayNpc that is why find is always 0 but your if statements cares about 0.25, 0.30 or 0.40 if you set your variable find as 0.25 it will do the first if.if  you set it 0.30 it will do the second if and if you set find 0.40 it will do the last one.So the problem here is just that find is never changed from 0.

Comment: Ok, i've tweaked a little bit, see what i'm going for.. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Please don't use float indices in a for. It's legal, it works but it's also not expected by most people :)

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz I've tweaked. But the thing is, when I type for exemple "0.2" it shows two warnings, the if (ind == 0.2) and the else if (ind == 0.4). what the hell? why?

Comment: Im using "double" now, instead of float.

Comment: @JayNpc it is because your if statements are in a for loop, with this code double ind=dic.nextDouble();  ind becomes 0.2 first and the first if works then the for loop keeps going after a while again with this code double ind=dic.nextDouble(); ind becomes 0.4 and this one works else if (ind == 0.4).As a result you get both of the prints, this is pretty normal and what it should be with your code.

Comment: So, for example, if I want to print only the warning that comes with my variable ( (ind == 0.4) warns every group) than i should separate the first if? is that what y r saying?

Comment: @JayNpc that wouldn't work perfectly in some cases, I added another code in my answer with break statements, try it.I hope it works.

Comment: OMG it did!!! thank you! LOL. I didn't even remembered to use "break". Saw that yesterday. Thanks @EmreVeriyaz. That problem is officially closed. But I'll start another one very soon and possibly i'll encounter some errors on the way, should I count with your help? I enjoyed very much (y) Thanks!

Comment: @JayNpc I am glad it worked and I could help Jay, as long as i am not afk i can try to help. Another thing you may want to learn is switch statement http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html you can use it in your code too, not that you have to but it looks betters.And also if my code worked for you, you can set it as your solution with clicking the tick on the left.Again, good luck on your programming journey :).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. All help noted (:

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz I'll lunch and than start a new problem. Is there anyway I can contact you through here?

Comment: @JayNpc I've got one more hour in my office I can try to help, than I wont have internet access.You go for it and ask your question, there are better programmers than me in stackoverflow they can help even if I cant, just be careful about how you ask your questions :)

Answer (score 7):

`if (find == 0.25)` - comparison is done via `==`, not `=`, which is for assignment.

The error message means that you are trying to assign a double value to a boolean (which is not possible)

By the way, your code might not work because of the way doubles are represented. If you want to have precise double calculations, either use `BigDecimal`, or use `int`s (your doubles multiplied by 10 or 100)

Answer (score 6):

Use `=` for assignment and `==` for equality-checks.

Later you'll stumble over the fact that floating point numbers don't work as you expect ...

Comment: and use .equals(other) and not == for equality checks on objects :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not always good to compare fractional numbers via `==`. Numbers are represented in the computer in a different way than we are writing, so `0.2 + 0.1` may be a tiny bit different from `0.3`. So instead of

```
if (ind == 0.2){
```

you'd better use something like

```
if (Math.abs(ind - 0.2) < 0.001){
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Bozho and Joachim answered the question, I will just add that `if` in java requires boolean expression inside and you give it the `double` - `find`. `(find = 0.25)` is assignment to find, but is not part of the evaluation. That's why you get

> it cannot convert double to boolean

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else said, watch out for the semi-colon at the end of the if-statement.

This piece of code:

```
if (find == 0.25);
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Will always print Hello.

However:

```
if (find == 0.25)
System.out.println("Hello");
```

This one will only print Hello if the if statement is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

if statement uses boolean values or expressions using operators like ==, !=, >, <, >= and <=.

I don't know what are you expecting from your code, but your "find" variable has no value, and you wanted to use "ind", it would go out of scope.

Your code has no way that it will ever have 0.25 anywhere

Comment: If you understood what i'm going for, how can I do it correctly?

Comment: @JayNpc I'm only pointing out that the variable that you declared in your for loop will cease to exist as soon the loop ends. You should review your code, and start with what you need to do and then divide the problem in smaller problems easier to fix. Your question as been answered and this is getting out of topic. In case of doubt, try to reproduce every step with values, etc. on paper. Your code is not that big so theres only a little patience required

Comment: Should I continue with my for loop and in sequence start with... my line of thought only gets that structure (the code above) in my head. Need help

Comment: if this is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696161/give-an-assignment-until-it-reaches-a-number-after-that-another-assignment-and  ... then you should start by organizing your thoughts, it gets easier if you think about the basic steps you mentally do

Answer (score 1):

```
double find;
    if (find = 0.25);
```

You're never assigning anyting to find, so the if (if you correct the == problem) will never be true.